# How deadlock and starvation problems occur in java producer consumer pattern.?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have written the following java code which shows the producer consumer  pattern.I want to know how deadlock and starvation occur in producer consumer pattern.I searched this query in internet.but i couldn't find a proper article which clearly explain how deadlock and starvation occur in producer consumer pattern.

```
public class InterThreadCommunication_Producer_Consumer {


        static Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        static int size = 4;




       public static void produce() throws InterruptedException {

                int value = 0;

                while(true) {


                    synchronized (queue) {


                        while(queue.size() >= size) {
                            queue.wait();
                        }


                        queue.add(value);


                        System.out.println("Produced" + value);

                        value++;


                        queue.notify();


                        Thread.sleep(1000);

                    }



                }


            }


            public static void consume() throws InterruptedException {

                while(true) {


                    synchronized (queue) {



                    while(queue.isEmpty()) {
                        queue.wait();
                    }


                    int value = queue.poll();

                    System.out.println("Consume" + value);

                    queue.notify();

                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }

                }



            }














        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

            Thread producerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        produce();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            Thread consumerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                       consume();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            producerThread.start();
            consumerThread.start();
            producerThread.join();
            consumerThread.join();

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do you have a deadlock?**

Deadlocks are not specific to collaboration patterns like Producer-Consumer, but come from locking patterns. With the one lock you have, you're safe.

For a deadlock you need at least two locks and two threads:

```
Time      0       1
Thread 1: Lock(A) Wait-Lock(B) 
Thread 2: Lock(B) Wait-Lock(A)
```

As you can see, at time 0 both threads are aquiring a lock to two resources. At time 1, they are waiting on each other without a non-collaborative possibility to go on.

**Notification policy**

Coming to your example: You are using `wait()` and `notify()` at two different threads with the same notification (`queue` object) which shows me that the notification is not belonging to a clear event (i.e. `queue` non-empty). This will lead to a problem, especially when you're working with more than 2 threads. You're reusing the same notification for:

1. data available
2. queuespace available

Notify the conditions you're waiting for in different objects. I also recommend reducing the scope of the critical sections (synchronized sections).